# Android sql query using WHERE clause for greater than

Tags: android, sql, database-design

I have a question regarding how to use a `WHERE` clause when querying a sql database in Android. I need to return specific records from my database where the value of DURATION is greater than 3.

It works fine when I have the WHERE clause for checking equals.
Example

```
Cursor resultOfFilterQuery = db.query(myTable, new String[] {call_cost, call_type,
                date,DURATION , phone_number }, phone_number= , new String[]{"9456788909"}, null, null, null);
```

Please let me know how to check for greater than
How should the query statement look?

```
Cursor resultOfFilterQuery = db.query(myTable, new String[] {call_cost, call_type,
                date,DURATION , phone_number }, DURATION>  , new String[]{3}, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know how your first code snippet work with syntax errors, but this can helps:

```
Cursor resultOfFilterQuery = db.query(myTable, 
         new String[] {call_cost, call_type, date, DURATION, phone_number }, 
         DURATION + "> ?", new String[]{"3"}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Hi.. I tried your approach. It worked for me. The first part of code had syntax errors but I was invoking it from a different method by passing it as arguments. Hence it was working for me. Thanks again for posting your reply..my code works with this approach.

Comment: @ Namratha : If someones answer is helpful for you then you should be accept it .